# Copy and paste excel data to another with condition using Openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

the logic flow will be this:
if the there is a username: "Administrator" in column B, copy the data, and paste it to another new Excel workbook. However, this code give me the following error:

> IndexError: list index out of range

```
def copyRange(startCol, startRow, endCol, endRow, sheet):
        rangeSelected = []
        #Loops through selected Rows
        for i in range(startRow,endRow + 1,1):
            #Appends the row to a RowSelected list
            rowSelected = []
            for j in range(startCol,endCol+1,1):
                if (sheet.cell(row = i, column = j).value) in adminlist:
                    rowSelected.append(sheet.cell(row = i, column = j).value)
            #Adds the RowSelected List and nests inside the rangeSelected
            rangeSelected.append(rowSelected)
        return rangeSelected
    
def pasteRange(startCol, startRow, endCol, endRow, sheetReceiving, copiedData):
        countRow = 0
        for i in range(startRow,endRow+1,1):
            countCol = 0
            for j in range(startCol,endCol+1,1):
                    
                sheetReceiving.cell(row = i, column = j).value = copiedData[countRow][countCol]
                countCol += 1
            countRow += 1
selectedRange = copyRange(1, 1, 13, sheet.max_row, sheet) #Change the 4 number values
pasteRange(1, 1, 13, sheet.max_row, Users_sheet, selectedRange) #Change the 4 number values
```

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work. Same error generated.

Comment: You should always include the full traceback in your question so others can see where the error is occurring and other details.

Comment: You mention ***if the there is a username: "Adminitrator" in column B*** (sic) however your loop in `copyRange` is checking all cells from column A to M (`endCol`). If you're looking for the value in Column why search these other columns?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for value in column B. If found, copy all data (the entire row) and paste in a new excel sheet.

Comment: The issue that I see causing the `"IndexError: list index out of range"` error is; You are appending the list `rowSelected` to the list rangeSelected at the end of each row checked, `rangeSelected.append(rowSelected)`

Comment: That means the list `rowSelected` has one element per row. You build this as a list of lists and only a row that did have the term `'Administrator'` will have a value in the sub list, the rest will be empty lists. When you attempt to access the list in the function `pasteRange` as copiedData[countRow][countCol] this double index will only work if the co-ordinates point to a list containing 'Administrator' otherwise you will get a index error.

Comment: Eg your list `rangeSelected` may look like this **[[], ['Administrator'], []]** So on the first loop  with `countRow` and `countCol` equal to 0 `copiedData[countRow][countCol]` would return an index error. Only when accessed using `copiedData[0][1]` would you get a value.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for explaining the root cause.  What should I do to correct the code?

Comment: ***Yes, I am looking for value in column B. If found, copy all data (the entire row) and paste in a new excel sheet.*** You don't need to search the whole row if you are only looking for your value in col B. If the value is found for the row you can use that cell as an center point as offset for the rest of the cells in the row. Also you can do this in one function not really necessary to create the list and then call another function to do the paste, just search col B then, make a list of the values in the row and Openpyxl `append` that to the  other sheet.

Comment: I tried to use the alternative method that you mentioned. But it seems like the data pasted without the formatting and the colors. It ends up looks like .csv form.

Comment: With Openpyxl when you copy a cell value it does not include any cell formatting or styling, only the value. Formatting/Styling must always be copied separately.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your reply! I will use the alternative method you mentioned and do the formatting and styling. Again, thanks!

Comment: And yes I transposed the index values in the example given in the earlier comment; `copiedData[0][1]` should be `copiedData[1][0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpler approach.
If you were just copying the values I would probably just create a list from the values in the source row then use `users_sheet.append` on the destination workbook to just append the list, meaning the row will be written to the next unused row in the destination sheet.
Since you want to copy the formatting/style of the cell then we copy the cells one by one and copy the formatting/style at the same time. `dst_row` is used to ensure the values are copied to the next unused row on the destination sheet.
This example doesn't copy the header row (starts writing on destination from row 1). If headers are needed same or other this will need to be added.

The example code is expanded to show the link between variables. Can be condensed where you understand what it's doing.

```
import openpyxl
from copy import copy
from openpyxl.utils.cell import column_index_from_string as cifs


src_file = 'data.xlsx'
wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(src_file)
sheet = wb1['Sheet1']

dst_file = 'foo.xlsx'
wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook(dst_file)
users_sheet = wb2['Sheet1']

### List to search or just a string if that's all that's being searched
search_list = ['administrator']  # Lower case to make search case-insensitive

### Search column
search_column = 'B'
search_col_int = cifs(search_column)

### Column Range A - M to copy in cell
### This can be set using column letter or use openpyxl sheet max value
start_col = 'A'
end_col = sheet.max_column+1
rng = range(cifs(start_col),end_col)

### Start writing on destination sheet from row 1
dst_row = 1  

### Looping col search_column only
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_col=search_col_int, max_col=search_col_int):
    ### Check cell value is in the search list.
    ### Convert to lower case for case-insensitive search
    if row[0].value.lower() in search_list:
        ### Use cell offsets for each cell in the row from Cols A - M
        for col in rng:  # Range Cols A - M
            dst_cell = users_sheet.cell(dst_row, col)
            ### Use cell offsets to get the cell value of all cells in the current row.
            ### Therefore row does not change. column cycles from A (-1) to M (11)
            src_cell = row[0].offset(row=0, column=col-search_col_int)

            ### Copy source cell value to destination cell
            dst_cell.value = src_cell.value

            ### If cell has a styles then copy this as well
            if src_cell.has_style:
                dst_cell.font = copy(src_cell.font)
                dst_cell.alignment = copy(src_cell.alignment)
                dst_cell.border = copy(src_cell.border)
                dst_cell.fill = copy(src_cell.fill)

                dst_cell.number_format = src_cell.number_format
        dst_row += 1  # Destination rows tracked

wb2.save(dst_file)
```